# Why does the smallest bubble size of this Highcharts jsFiddle example seem incorrect and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a bubble map and am having a problem with the smallest bubble sizes which are not behaving as I expect. After searching a bit in the documentation to understand the problem, I found this:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.sizeBy

I don't want to change the setting for 'sizeBy' from its default Area (that makes the most sense for my data) but there is helpful example alongside the API entry in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/bubble-sizeby/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles Sizing'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Smallest and largest bubbles are equal, intermediate bubbles different.'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3],
            [4, 4, 4],
            [5, 5, 5]
        ],
        sizeBy: 'area',
        name: 'Size by area'
    }, {
        data: [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3],
            [4, 4, 4],
            [5, 5, 5]
        ],
        sizeBy: 'width',
        name: 'Size by width'
    }]
});
```

Keeping in mind that I'm only nterested in showing by Area (the default), what I don't understand about the example is why the first bubble (which has a z value of 1) is so small compared to the other bubbles. It's area should be 0.5 times the area of the second bubble (which has a z value of 2). But it's much much smaller (like 1/10 of the area). All of the other bubbles however seem to be proportionally correct — it's really just that first bubble.

So my question is — why is the first bubble so small and is there a way to prevent this from happening so that all of the bubbles are proportionate according to area?

Many thanks in advance,

David

Follow-up:

I created a more extreme example in jsFiddle with only two bubbles — one is half the value of the other so it's area (or width) should also be half — but it's not.

https://jsfiddle.net/2m75nwhf/1/

I could be completely misunderstanding the API but I thinking now this is probably just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `minSize` property. In Highcharts API we can read:

> **minSize: number, string**
>
> Minimum bubble size. Bubbles will automatically size between the
> minSize and maxSize to reflect the z value of each bubble. Can be
> either pixels (when no unit is given), or a percentage of the smallest
> one of the plot width and height.

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5kspqn1h/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.maxSize

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.minSize

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure that fixes the problem — minSize seems to specify the minimum bubble size to use but it doesn't take into account the actual value. In your fiddle you hardcoded a value of 15 and even though the lowest value one is taking that as its bubble size it is still the wrong area size for the data point (the bubble area for the z=1  is a lot less than half the area for the bubble z=2). You could manually adjust the minSize still you got a value that was correct but I don't know in advance what the minimum value  will be so need to do it programatically.

Comment: Hi @pingin, You can check how exactly the size is calculated here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Series/Bubble/BubbleSeries.ts#L503-L550 Could you provide more details why do you think that the bubble sizes are not correct?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, the easiest way to see what I mean is to look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2m75nwhf/1/ The value of bubble in the bottom left (A) is 1 and of the bubble on the top right (B) is value 2. The area of A should be 0.5 times the area of B. or a circle this means the radius of A should be approx 0.7 times the radius of B — but it's not. It's a lot less as you can see in the example.I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You are partially right, but this is compatible with the description in the API: `Minimum bubble size. Bubbles will automatically size between the minSize and maxSize to reflect the z value of each bubble.`. I would suggest you to calculate `maxSize` based on your data, before creating a chart.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've fixed this for the moment is I create a fake data point with a value that is lower than other values in the dataset. I'm posting here in case anyone else has a similar problem. If there was a way to do this through the API, that would be preferable and I would remove this code. I will keep searching for a more elegant solution.

After the bubble map is drawn, I then remove the fake data point.

So I have something like;

```
 var minValue = 0.0000000001; // some fake minimum value (or better, calculate it programmatically from the actual data)

        data.push({.  // this is how I am structuring the data for my data set
            id: "fakeMinValue", 
            lat: 50, // these lat/lon values give a location somewhere in France — it's important to make sure the lon/lat values are on within your actual map
            lon: 2,  
            z: minValue
        })
```

Then I draw my map...

```
        var bubbleMap = Highcharts.mapChart(containerID, {
           ...
        }
```

and after it's drawn, in the code I then remove the fake data point with this command:

```
 bubbleMap.get('fakeMinValue').remove(false); // 'false' prevents HighMaps from redrawing the map without the fake data point which would otherwise defeat the purpose
```